# AVA: does not show failed tests within a timeout, only passed

Tags: ava

Any output method I use with AVA, e.g. Verbose, a reporter, or its default, always outputs the passed tests, but never the failed tests.

It's becoming increasingly difficult to figure out which tests failed and why (without process of elimination, which isn't ideal):

```
  ✖ Exited because no new tests completed within the last 10000ms of inactivity

  55 tests passed [09:38:58]
  1 uncaught exception
```

Preferably, I want to know which of the tests failed within the timeout, not passed - I have a total of 59 tests.

Has anyone achieved this in AVA?

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone achieved this in AVA?

No, but there's an open issue: https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/583.